# Blazor Server Side Login Page Not Redirecting on Chrome

Tags: google-chrome, authentication, blazor-server-side, asp.net-identity-3

I am running into a weird issue/bug with Blazor Server Side and ASP.NET Core Identity, and it only happens on Chrome.  It works perfectly on Microsoft Edge.  Basically to login, I am using the default ASP.NET Identity Razor Page (i.e. /Identity/Account/Login) that has been scaffolded in my project since there are issues using signInManager and userManager in Blazor components.  The problem is that when I first launch my project from Visual Studio and try to sign in, it gets "stuck" trying to login (i.e. the redirect to the returnUrl never completes).  I just see a message at the bottom of Chrome saying "Processing Request".  Now, if I just navigate to the page directly, it will show me as signed in.  Subsequent login/logout requests work perfectly.  It only happens when I try to sign in the first time.  I've done my research, and I'm out of ideas of what could be causing the problem.  I've even played around with the AspNetCore.Identity.Application cookie and thought it might have something to do with SameSite attribute.  I changed it to from Lax to Strict, but the problem still persists.  If anyone has any ideas, I would appreciate you sharing.

Comment: I got the same problem on Microsoft Edge Canary. On the Microsoft Edge (stable) works.

Comment: Thanks for confirming, Henrique.  I ended up not handling login this way but am now using Chris Sainty's implementation of [JSON Web tokens](https://chrissainty.com/securing-your-blazor-apps-authentication-with-clientside-blazor-using-webapi-aspnet-core-identity/).

Answer (score 3):

This appears to only be an issue in chrome when using a development certificate for https. After publishing to IIS and using a valid ssl cert, the problem appears resolved.